# Diamond structure factor as product of FCC and BCC structure factors

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, crystals, x-ray-crystallography

I need help understanding why the step on this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_factor#Diamond_crystal_structure) is true. Why does the structure factor of the diamond lattice is the product of the structure factor of a BCC Lattice and a FCC lattice?

> But comparing this to the FCC above, we see that it is simplier to describe the structure as FCC with a basis of two atoms at $(0,0,0)$ and $(1/4,1/4,1/4)$. For this basis, Equation (8) becomes:
> $$F_{hkl}(\text{basis})=f\sum_{j=1}^2 e^{-2\pi i(hx_j+ky_j+lz_j)}=f\left[1+e^{-i\pi/2(h+k+l)}\right]=f\left[1+(-i)^{h+k+l}\right]\tag{1}$$
> And the structure factor for the diamond cubic structure is the product of this and the structure factor for FCC above, (only including the atomic form factor once)
> $$F_{hkl}=f\left[1+(-1)^{h+k}+(-1)^{k+l}+(-1)^{h+l}\right]\times\left[1+(-i)^{h+k+l}\right]\tag{2}$$

Intuitively this feels obvious, because as there are these two patterns in the lattice then it has to respect both structure factors simultaneously. However I keep getting stuck on the mathematics: Suppose $d_i$ are the basis vectors for an FCC lattice and $d_j$ are the basis vectors for a BCC lattice. Then, supposing that the structure factor for diamond is in fact the product of these two lattice's, then:

$$
S_G=\sum_{i,j}e^{i\vec{G}\cdot(\vec{d_i}+\vec{d_j})}
\tag{3}$$

but both basis account for the $\vec{0}$ vector so I would be overcounting, saying that I have two atoms at the origin. As opposed to that, I could say that the diamond lattice has a basis consisting of all the $d_i$ and all the $d_j$ **except** one of the null vectors, and that would certainly give me a different result. This doubt of mine arises from my attempt to calculate the structure factor for a perovskite since it is a superposition (not the quantum one) of a BCC and an FCC lattice, so it would be quite straightforward to calculate that. Where am I wrong?

Comment: That page is (properly) not suggesting that diamond cubic is a combination of BCC and FCC, but rather of FCC and the two-atom basis. Further, a crystal structure is _either_ BCC or FCC, not both at once (since that yields different symmetries).

Comment: Yes, I see now how trying to describe a perovskite as an FCC with a two atom basis with one at the origin and another at (0.5,0.5,0.5) would result in overcounting atoms. But I still can't see how that step in calculation is made, other than getting the reciprocal basis of an fcc basis and do the structure factor as usual. But they make it seem like it's something obvious, is it really that obvious?

Comment: the convolution theorem?